# Joining 2 aliased tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 snipets of code. 
What I want is to join 2 tables. I thought about something like this for joining.

```
with CH_AL_SDB as
(
  select sr13.*, sr14.*
  from sr13, sr14
  where sr14.SUBS_KEY = sr13.S_CTN_MAIN
)select * from CH_AL_SDB;
```

Here I select from one table.

```
with sr13 as
(
  select distinct CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY, count(CTN_MAIN) as CTN_QUANTITY
  from ETL1_ETL.STG_SDB_LOAD SDB
  group by CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY
)select * from sr13;
```

Here from the second table.

```
with sr14 as
(
  select FPCN.*
  from FCT_PREP_CHARGES_N FPCN
    where FPCN.business_service_key = 33006
    and CHARGE_TYPE='R'
)select * from sr14;
```

Aliases are not necessary. It's just the only thing I could come up with so far. The problem is sr14 after execution has 39 columns. sr13 has 4. There should be 43 in the result, but there are 35. When I select all 3 queries and run them in sql developer. columns from sr13 don't appear at all. And there are 4 columns from sr14 missing. Names of columnes from sr13 and sr14 that are missing are different.

In sqldeveloper the order is

```
CH_AL_SDB
sr13
sr14
```

when I change it to

```
CH_AL_SDB
sr14
sr13
```

only 4 columns from sr13 appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this

```
with CH_AL_SDB as
(
    select distinct SDB.CTN_MAIN as S_CTN_MAIN, 
      SDB.SUBS_KEY as S_SUBS_KEY, 
      SDB.BAN_KEY as S_BAN_KEY, 
      count(SDB.CTN_MAIN) as CTN_QUANTITY,
      FPCN.BAN_KEY
    from STG_SDB_LOAD SDB
    inner join FCT_PREP_CHARGES_N FPCN
    on FPCN.SUBS_KEY = SDB.CTN_MAIN
    group by CTN_MAIN, 
      SDB.SUBS_KEY, 
      SDB.BAN_KEY, 
      FPCN.BAN_KEY
)select * from CH_AL_SDB;
```

In group by I added just FPCN.BAN_KEY to make it short, but I'll need to list all damn fields.

Update

Here is a better way

```
with sr13 as
(
  select distinct CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY, count(CTN_MAIN) as CTN_QUANTITY
  from ETL1_ETL.STG_SDB_LOAD SDB
  group by CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY
),
sr14 as
(
  select FPCN.*
  from FCT_PREP_CHARGES_N FPCN
    where FPCN.business_service_key = 33006
    and CHARGE_TYPE='R'
)
  select sr13.*, sr14.*
  from sr13, sr14
  where sr14.SUBS_KEY = sr13.S_CTN_MAIN
```